# Lightbox is only showing a black background instead of the image ontop in IE8 and IE7

Tags: jquery, html, css

Link: http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/portfolio.html

I'm trying to make this lightbox work in IE7 and 8. It seems to be working fine in any other browser. I've read online that this could be a problem with html5 and I would have to strip out all my html5 tags to fix this which I obviously don't want to do.

The lightbox just shows a black screen where the image would sit ontop

I was wondering if anyone knows a fix to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: try to use [HTML5Shim-els](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/source/browse/trunk/html5-els.js?r=12) instead of your current shim

Comment: Doesn't seem to of done the trick this time round. Any other ideas?